# __proto__ workaround for Internet Explorer IE 10

Tags: javascript, html, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

We're using a custom JavaScript library at work where we do this:

```
DOM.__proto__ = Library.prototype;
```

to quickly transfer internal functions/properties DOM objects so that it can be used similar to how jQuery for example does it.

For a new project we need to implement it for Internet Explorer but unfortunately `__proto__` is not supported by IE.

Any ideas, workarounds of polyfills for this? The requirement is IE10 only (but IE9 would be nice too).

Comment: It's very unlikely to have a good solution. You can only *extend* the prototype in IE rather than replace/hijack/inject/whatever the prototype of another object.

Comment: Ok, but how would extending it look like in IE?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning to `__proto__` after creating the `DOM` object, use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff925952(v=vs.94).aspx), supported since IE9) to *create* the object with the correct prototype, and then afterwards assign properties to it.

```
var DOM = {};
DOM.__proto__ = Library.prototype;
```

```
var DOM = Object.create(Library.prototype);
```

If you wanted to modify the prototype of existing (and maybe even foreign) objects, just avoid it. It's a bad practise anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly extending the DOM element as you are, you could wrap it with your API;

```
// Wrapping Constructor
function Library(element) {
  this.element = element;
}

// Whatever it is your library does
Library.prototype = {
  // some example method
  html: function(markup) {
    // refer to "this.element" instead of "this"
    this.element.innerHTML = markup;
  }
};

// example
var wrappedElement = new Library(document.getElementById('unique'));

// refer to the API rather than the Element directly
wrappedElement.html('<span>Hello World</span>');
```

You can also extend Library some more by [safely subclassing Array with this technique](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/11/hooray/).

Hope this helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about extending it:

```
$.extend(Element.constructor.prototype, Library.prototype);
```

EDIT: due to *public outcry*, I'll note that `extend` is a very familiar concept in the context of JS programming in the year of 2014. You may find online numerous examples of what it is and how it works, and there's a pretty damn good chance at least one library you use already in your project implements it (jQuery, Lo-Dash/Underscore, AngularJS, Ember.js...)

Comment: Even that `jQuery` is mention in the question it is still a general one and not related to `jQuery`, so you still should mention that `$.extend` is part of the jQuery library. As this might not be obvious for every reader.

Comment: @t.niese Unless someone has been living in a cave for the last ten years, I think they know that `$` indicates jQuery.

Comment: @torazaburo there are still enough people not being able to distinguish between js, jQuery, ... and here on SO there are enough question that show that people don't know that they are using jQuery when there is a `$`. Additionally `$` is not reserved to jQuery. While it is currently the mayor library it does does not need to be the library in future. So I still think either writing `jQuery.extend()` or mentioning that it is from jQuery would be a good thing.

Comment: There is certainly no harm in highlighting that, for sure.

Comment: It also should be noted that `extend` is a very basic feature and can be trivially used without depending on the whole jQuery library.

Comment: @t.niese Come on, virtually *every* popular framework/library these days comes with *some* version of `extend`. What's more, it shouldn't be that difficult for programmers with the experience of writing their own library (as the OP said), to write their own `extend`, too.

Comment: _public outcry_ ;) I know I this might be nit picking, but I still think it is something to be mentioned. The  `$('element')` vs `$('#element')` _problem_ you had when jQuery was not the major library is just one example. It is not uncommon that a new major library  arises over time and there even _basic_ functions may change their signature, leaving not updated tutorials/answers in the net that are not wrong but cause of the _inaccuracy_ misleading. In the end it is up to you wether you add those information or not. But I still think it is a good thing to add those informations.

Comment: @t.niese I get what you're trying to say, but you're ignoring two key points: usually, libraries which have just "appeared" are still in a development stage, and it's expected of them to evolve and change - that's open source for you. And if the developers care about their community, they will also usually tag their library as "a WIP", "don't use in production", etc. And lastly, the `extend` concept is already well known and widely used these days, making our little discussion here slightly moot.